# Time travel novel or series involving a professor at the Citadel who identifies the point of deviation

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, alternate-history

There were two apparent timelines -  the 1st was thought to be unchangeable until the plot happened; a key person in identifying the point of deviation between the two timelines was a professor at the Citadel military college in South Carolina, in the present day, who retained his memories from the previous timeline and who becomes interested in his student (a pilot hero, who I think became a cyborg, but do not take my word for it).

The professor was like a second generation German immigrant - this became important to the resolution of the POD.

Comment: What citadel are you referring to? This one (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Citadel) or one that exists in-universe or what?

Comment: It was the one in South Carolina. Also the professor was like a second generation German immigrant- this became important to the resolution of the POD

Comment: I do think it matches, but the original book of The Man in the High Castle is ringing a few bells here so thought it worth a mention https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_High_Castle

Comment: Perhaps related, there was a real professor at the Citadel (Michael Barrett) who specialized in German history, and was a general in the US Army.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly [*The Gordian Protocol*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/40963723-the-gordian-protocol) by David Weber.

I never actually finished this book (I read just over half of it a few years ago) but some of your elements seem to match my memories of it. It follows Doctor Benjamin Schröder, Chairman of the Castle Rock University history department, who teams up with Commander Abramowski, a highly decorated Navy fighter pilot, after he has what he initially believes to be a psychotic break, where he's flooded with memories of our timeline, where the Holocaust happened.

Comment: Seems to be it, thank you, I may now read it again

Comment: There are 2 further books set in the same universe - I haven't read them

Comment: 4 books now. 2nd book is broadly similar - time travel, multiverse, etc. The 3rd and 4th are essentially detective stories - all quite enjoyable, at least for me.